# How to mimic SwiftUI List's data-less initializers when wrapping UITableView

Tags: uitableview, swiftui, swiftui-list, uiviewrepresentable

Apple offers the following SwiftUI `List` initializer:

`List<SelectionValue: Hashable, Content: View>.init(selection: Binding<SelectionValue?>?, content: () -> Content)`

I would like to make a similar component, but customizing some of the `UITableView` behaviors not exposed in `List`. Also, I would like to mirror this single-selection, data-less initializer, because I don't have much arbitrary data, and would like to define my rows in-line in a ViewBuilder closure. So, wrapping `UITableView`:

```swift
struct CustomizedList<SelectionValue: Hashable, Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {

  @Binding var selection: SelectionValue
  @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.delegate = context.coordinator
    tableView.dataSource = content.coordinator
    return tableView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ tableView: UITableView, context: Context) {
    // todo
  }

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }

  final class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    private var parent: CustomizedList

    init(_ parent: CustomizedList) {
      self.parent = parent
    }

    // delegate methods to customize behavior
    // ...

    // data source methods

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      // ???
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      // ???
    }
  }
}
```

What do I do in the data source delegate methods? Since `List` is a wrapper around `UITableView`, how is Apple implementing the data source delegate methods for the data-less initializers of `List`? (Also notice that for `List`'s data initializers, `Data` is only a generic of the initializer, not `List` itself.)

Is it possible to use `UITableView` without a data source, and just pass on the `Content` (with some `View`-to-`UIView` wrapping)?